# Compare two multidimensional arrays and unset matched elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**UPDATE:** After the replies I got I realized I shoud be trying to solve this already with the database query so I wrote [a more detailed post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521876/retrieving-available-rooms-and-their-beds-for-a-given-date-range-from-database)

**ORIGINAL POST:**
I would like to compare two multidimensional arrays and get rid of the elements that match a certain criteria. I know I will have to loop through the arrays with some keys and then unset, but I can't seem to do it properly.

The two arrays are `$all` which has stored all available rooms and their beds and `$reserved` which has only reserved rooms and the reserved beds.

I want to loop through all the reservations and take the room title which is on position `$reservations[x][0]` where x is the currently viewed reservation and compare it with all elements in `$all[a][0]` where a is the currently viewed room.

So then when I find that value of `$all[0][0]` => 'Luxury Room' matches with `$reservations[0][0]` => 'Luxury Room' I will look at the beds and a bed code on position y where y is the currently viewed bed code `$reservations[x][1][y]` and compare it with all available beds for the matched room so with `$all[0][1][b]` where b are all the available rooms.

And when I find out that value of `$all[0][1][1]`=>'xx2' matches the value in `$reservations[0][1][0]`=>'xx2' I will unset index [0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521876/retrieving-available-rooms-and-their-beds-for-a-given-date-range-from-database)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521876/retrieving-available-rooms-and-their-beds-for-a-given-date-range-from-database) from `$all`

so finally when I will loop through the `$all` array and would list each element's index [0] as title and elements of the array on index [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521876/retrieving-available-rooms-and-their-beds-for-a-given-date-range-from-database) as beds I would only get bed 'xx2' as available for the 'Luxury Room'

```
//$all is an array where index 0 is an array   
$all = array( 0=>array(
                    //index 0 has value 'Luxury Room' (room title)
                    0=>'Luxury Room',
                    //index 1 is an array
                    1=>array(
                            //where index 0 has value 'xx1' (bed code)
                            0=>'xx1',
                            //where index 1 has value 'xx2' (bed code)
                            1=>'xx2')),
            //again index 1 is an array etc. just as above...
            1=>array(
                    0=>'Cheap Room',
                    1=>array(
                            0=>'zz1',
                            1=>'zz2',
                            2=>'zz3',
                            3=>'zz4')));

$reserved = array( 0=>array(
                    0=>'Luxury Room',
                    1=>array(0=>'xx2')));
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it via proper database queries instead of dealing with this monstrosity? Just curious.

Comment: There might be but I didn't get anywhere as far in with that idea. Basically I have a table rooms which has an ID and BEDS is int with the total count of beds. So then I wanted to convert that through a loop into that simple array cause in the end all I need is the available room IDs with their available Beds.. Second table is reservations which has FROM (date), TO(date), ROOMS_ID(int) and BED_NUMBER (int)

Comment: But I have no idea how to write a query that would take the available rooms. compare them with the date ranges in the reservations for each rooms and its beds and then return a table that has only the ROOMS_IDs and the bed numbers in each field..

Comment: You should use associative arrays rather than numeric arrays for heterogeneous items.

Comment: You should re-formulate your question and make it about SQL instead. Something along the lines of "how can I do this via SQL?" and show us your table structures and the desired output. Dealing with arrays like this is not efficient in any way, shape or form.

Comment: ok I am taking this down and will try to write a better question on sql tomorrow. I just realized I dont even know how to optimize this for a given time range.. This is hard. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested loops:

```
foreach ($all as &$room) {
    foreach ($reserved as $r) {
        if ($room[0] == $r[0]) { // same types of room
            foreach ($room[1] as $i => $code) {
                if (in_array($code, $r[1])) {
                    unset($room[1][$i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $room[1] = array_values($room[1]); // Reset array indexes
}
```

The `$all` loop uses a reference for the iteration variable so that the `unset()` calls modify the original array.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/ilppwy)

Comment: this is absolutely correct and what I was trying to do this whole time. I now know that just this won't be enough though, because I still have to only unset rooms that have beds reserved for all the days for which a person is trying to make a reservation. So I'm starting again from the query..