# Retrieving available rooms and their beds for a given date range from database

Tags: php, mysql, date, for-loop

I have read carefuly through all the posts on here about this topic, but my question has one extra catch, where I need to get available beds of each room because its a hostel and some rooms are shared.

Now I have tried doing this in [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516778/compare-two-multidimensional-arrays-and-unset-matched-elements), but then realized I haven't even taken in account the date range. So now I am thinking since I already have a query that retrieves all reservations occurring within a given date range and then compare the retrieved rooms and their beds with the room table and show only rooms and their beds that are not occupied. But I can't figure out how to work around the beds because they are not an entity, only a count of total beds in each room. But then a reservation says for which bed in the room that reservation is made..

Here are my tables

**Rooms**

[image]

**Reservations**

[image]

Now the query that I use to retrieve all reserved rooms and their beds is

```
SELECT rooms_id, bed 
FROM reservations 
WHERE `to` > '2016-02-18' AND `from` < '2016-02-24'
```

The first date if my input variable $from and the second date is input variable $to and it allows to retrieve not only rooms that have a reservation that starts within $from and $to but also all reservations that started before the date range and end inside, started inside and end after the date range and finally reservations that started before and end after the date range. So this exact query above would return the following table

[image]

which I can then visualize in my app like this
[image]

But this is where I get stuck. I have no idea how to match the data I have in order to find all available rooms BUT ALSO THE BEDS.
The desired table **AVAILABLE ROOMS** for the date range from '2016-02-18' and to '2016-02-24' should look like this:

```
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|| rooms_id || bed_number ||
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
||    1     ||    1       ||
----------------------------
||    1     ||    2       ||
----------------------------
||    2     ||    5       ||
----------------------------
||    2     ||    6       ||
----------------------------
||    2     ||    7       ||
----------------------------
||    2     ||    8       ||
----------------------------
```

You can see this in the picture where I show how it looks in my app. The only rooms and beds that are available between the two dates are the Luxury Room and its bed number 1 and bed number 2 and the Dorm rooms beds 5,6,7,8 because 1-4 have a reservation occurring on at least on one of the desired dates

The only idea I had was using NOT IN, but that only works if I didn't care about the beds and also the output is of here it is

```
SELECT *
FROM `rooms`
WHERE `id` NOT IN
     (SELECT rooms_id FROM reservations WHERE `to` > '2016-02-18' AND `from` < '2016-02-24')
```

[image]

instead of what I "sketched" above

I'd appreciate any tips and ideas on how approach this.
Part of me worries that this will all come down to me not treating the beds as entities and having to do that, even though as I will **never be storing** any sort of information on the beds such as their color, position, quality, price, etc...

**REPLY TO @Paul-Spiegel**

That is amazing, but is there any way to get the free beds as numbers as well instead of total number. Because then when the person makes a reservation I have to assign it to on of the beds. So if the result could be

```
| room_id | title       | beds_total | available_bed_nrs |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
| 1       | luxury room | 2          | 1, 2              |
| 2       | dorm room   | 8          | 5, 6, 7, 8        |
```

instead of

[image]

Comment: "But then a reservation says for which bed in the room that reservation is made." in which case, they *are* an entity!

Comment: You should make a sqlfiddle from http://sqlfiddle.com/ with you data  abd schema so the experts can easily help u

Comment: @Strawberry ok, but only in the table reservations right? because table rooms only says how many beds each rooms has

Comment: A guest arrives at a room, which is already occupied but all beds are made and the other occupant(s) are not present. How does the guest know which bed is theirs?

Comment: @Strawberry you got me worried there, but I just confirmed with the Hostel that they don't care which bed the person takes.. They will just put like a note on each available bed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a number of free rooms (and the reserved room numbers) with this query:

```sql
set @from := '2016-02-18';
set @to   := '2016-02-24';
set @beds := 1;

SELECT rm.id, rm.title, rm.beds,
    rm.beds - IFNULL(rv.num_reserved_beds, 0) AS num_free_beds,
    rv.reserved_bed_nrs
FROM rooms rm
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT rv.rooms_id, 
        COUNT(1) as num_reserved_beds, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(rv.bed) as reserved_bed_nrs
    FROM reservations rv
    WHERE rv.from < @to
      AND rv.to   > @from
    GROUP BY rv.rooms_id
) rv ON rv.rooms_id = rm.id
HAVING num_free_beds >= @beds
```

You can now parse `reserved_bed_nrs`, loop over all beds per room and pick the beds that are not in `reserved_bed_nrs`.

**Explaination:**

Get all beds reserved within date range (excluding):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM reservations r
WHERE r.from < @to
  AND r.to   > @from;
```

Group by room, count the number of reserved rooms and store all numbers of reserved rooms in one string field:

```sql
SELECT rv.rooms_id, 
    COUNT(1) as num_reserved_beds, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(rv.bed) as reserved_bed_nrs
FROM reservations rv
WHERE rv.from < @to
  AND rv.to   > @from
GROUP BY rv.rooms_id
```

Join (LEFT JOIN) `rooms` with the given result calculate the number of free beds and compare it with the number of beds you want to book.

**Update** How to get free (not reserved) beds:

If you don't have a table with all existing beds, you will need some kind of sequece numbers. Assuming a room can have a maximum of 100 beds you can create a `sequence` table with 100 numbers:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sequence` (
    `nr` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`nr`)
) select d1.d*10 + d0.d + 1 as nr   from 
    (select 0 d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d0,
    (select 0 d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d1
```

Now it's possible to list all existing beds by cross joining the tables `rooms` and `sequence`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM rooms rm 
CROSS JOIN sequence seq
WHERE seq.nr <= rm.beds
```

To list all **not resverd** beds you can combine it with a query for reserved beds (select all beds that are not reserved within the booking date range):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM rooms rm 
CROSS JOIN sequence seq
WHERE seq.nr <= rm.beds
  AND (rm.id, seq.nr) NOT IN (
        SELECT rv.rooms_id, rv.bed
        FROM reservations rv
        WHERE rv.from < '2016-02-24'
          AND rv.to   > '2016-02-18'
  )
```

This can also be done with `NOT EXISTS` or excluding `LEFT JOIN`.

You also can skip the creation of the `sequence` table use the creation code as subselect:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM rooms rm 
CROSS JOIN (
    select d1.d*10 + d0.d + 1 as nr
    from 
    (select 0 d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d0,
    (select 0 d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d1
) seq
WHERE seq.nr <= rm.beds
  AND (rm.id, seq.nr) NOT IN (
        SELECT rv.rooms_id, rv.bed
        FROM reservations rv
        WHERE rv.from < '2016-02-24'
          AND rv.to   > '2016-02-18'
  )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0d61/5

Comment: I rejected your edit. The same text is already in your question.

Comment: I understand, I wanted to delete it but it wouldnt let me.. So is there a way to adjust the query to do that? Or can it only be done like you say and the rest will have to be done in php? Nevermind just saw the update pop up. Reading through it now. THank you

Comment: That is amazing. I would have never thought this could be done only with SQL. Thank you so much. One question, to get this sort of "thinking"/ ideas are there any books I could read or is it just overall database knowledge and practice?

Comment: I'm sure there are many books available. But i can't suggest one, because i've never read them. For me it's like 50% reading documentation, 50% rading stackoverflow and 100% practice and experimenting ;-). It also helps to split a problem into small parts. If you do that, you will see that every subproblem of your question is already solved on stackoverflow. You just need to combine the solutions.